# Hair particles rendering white dots

Tags: hair

When I use Hemi light to do rendering I got white dots on hair particles, but when I use sun light it shows no such issue, what am I doing wrong? Cuz the issue goes away when I do not use the glossy shader for making my hair more gloss like.

When with hemi light rendered:
[image]

When with sun light rendered:
[image]

Shader nodes I used to create the shiny hair effect:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the white dots is solved, I used different node setup, now it looks much better with hemi light as well:

[image]

Here's the node setup I used:

[image]